Is there a way to get a list of directly included files within a script?
By which, I don't mean a list of everything included recursively, as returned by get_included_files(). I'm really quite surprised to find that, as far as I can tell, nobody has asked this question before, as it seems like it'd be a relatively commonly-required feature!

"as it seems like it'd be a relatively commonly-required feature" - I've been programming with PHP for 15+ years and I don't think I've ever had a need for this. I'm not saying your request isn't valid, I'm just saying I've never had a need for it, nor can I imagine a need for one.

Same for me. What is the purpose why you need this?

Surely you can just grep the file for include or require lines?

There's lots of stuff recursively included for request handling, database access, etc in each page, and generally UI logic and templates are included at that first level only. Plus I'm asking with a view towards building some sort of tree or hierarchy, partially or wholly of what is included where, which becomes far trickier when the whole lost of files just appears in a flat 1D array.

@ADyson done that with PHPstorm's search, using regular expressions. It becomes clunky when an included file path is a variable or concatenation of them.

This is just my opinion, so please don't take it as an attack, but if you are running into recursive file inclusion to the point that you are considering building a UI to help resolve it, I think you might be doing something the hard way. Legacy code is its own problem, so if that's where you are it, ignore this. The *_once versions of including often solve lots of problems. Also defining an autoload and/or a universal boot script that everyone uses. Templates are more complicated, but there's ways to solve that, too.

It is legacy code

There's also something of a bit of, not so much annoyance, but closer to bewilderment that beyond a simple list of the entire 'include-ome', there's no way to output anything more fine-grained or with some hierarchical info for a currently executing script.

Well, are you aware of any other languages that offer this? It's usually up to the programmer to manage their file structure (possibly with help from an IDE), not the language itself.

done that with PHPstorm's search, using regular expressions. It becomes clunky when an included file path is a variable or concatenation of them...true, but it gives you a starting point, surely? I was kind of assuming this might be for a one-off audit? So you can then rationalise it? If you have paths which are built from runtime variable values then making a tool which can analyse the code and build the correct paths outside of that runtime is going to be very tricky, if not impossible. How many files do you need to analyse in this way? Perhaps you can do part of it by hand.

If I really would need this I would write a wrapper function and replace all includes and requires with my wrapper. Then you can log everything as you need.

@ADyson no; I did think PHP might be unique (perhaps flawed even) in allowing includes that just become part of the current variable scope, but I just refreshed my knowledge of Perl and that does the same thing with its modules if variables are not explicitly declared with a 'my' or other keyword. Indeed, perhaps I was asking too much.
To your second comment, it's no big audit or anything, just something which, if it existed as some extension or undocumented function, I might have found useful once or twice. Your remarks about the difficulty of it all kind of prove what I already suspected.

@MarkusZeller I assume you mean outputting the paths which would otherwise just be passed to include/require? That is a nice simple solution that takes care of runtime-built paths, which for whatever reason escaped me. Thanks, it seems to be the best/only way of achieving this.
